# Cut the data from different rows and columns in unix at the same time

Tags: bash, unix, awk, cut

I'm working in a shell script code where in I need to take the value from 8th column from the 2nd and the last row. I tried implementing the `cut` command but I'm exactly not sure how to do it for columns and rows at the same time.

Data from where i need to cut:

```
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC    YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT

 12.44   0.00  27.20   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672

 12.44   0.00  62.16   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672

 12.44   0.00  83.97   9.49  96.70    78    0.176     5    0.495    0.672
```

So i would be needing the 8th Column (FGC) first row value (5) and 8th Column last row value(5).

My code:

```
gc=$(jstat -gcutil 21891 250 3)
fgc=`echo $gc | cut -f8 -d' '`
echo "$fgc"
```

this give me FGC column name but not the value. Kindly help me on this. thanks.

Comment: Do you know the row count or would you like the more generic _last row_?

Comment: @JamesBrown just the second row and the last row (as the first row has headers). only the FGC column value

Comment: `awk 'NR==2 {print $8} END{print $8}' <<< "$gc"`?

Comment: for all the above and below mentioned methods, i only get the get the second row value and not the last row

Comment: Upload output of `jstat -gcutil 21891 250 3` somewhere and add link here.

Comment: you can use the same data which i pasted in the question and take it to a text file. and try this command 
`awk 'NR == 2 { print $8 } END { print $8 }' < text.file`

the output should be 5 (second row output) and 5 (last row output)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
jstat -gcutil 21891 250 3 | awk 'NR == 2 { print $8 } END { print $8 }'
```

Comment: We were pretty close. ++

Comment: @codeforester  could you please write it in one line. i dont get any output for the above you tried. im just trying to understand.

`gc=$(jstat -gcutil 21891 250 3)`

`awk '
    NR == 2 { print $8 }
                  { value = $8 } 
    END       { print value }' $gc`

Comment: It's not the issue with the number of lines - you can simply concat them.  You are missing the `|`.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. it worked now. I missed the `|` symbol as your said. I see only one `5` being generated in the output rather two. i should be having the output of the first line and the last line.. right ?

Comment: Working fine for me.  Are you sure `jstat` is giving the right output?

Comment: `jstat -gcutil 21891 250 3 | awk 'NR == 2 { print $8 } END { print $8 }'`

output:
18

"[weblogic.....

i see an empty line coming .

Comment: Pipe jstat output through `grep -v '^$'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146476/discussion-between-dev-and-codeforester).